# Pycharm ненормально распечатывает код

Tags: pycharm, печать

Печатает растягивая текст кода и смещая его вправо, правая часть кода обрезается (хотя строки не длинные), поля справа игнорируются и текст кода почти до самого края страницы. Менял настройки в "Print" Pycharm, делал отступ меньше - не помогло. Сам принтер печатает нормально, в настройках указано печать с полями.

Comment: Ух ты, впервые вижу чтобы кому нибудь понадобилось распечатывать код из IDE

Comment: Иногда могу забыть как работает тот или иной механизм и хочется чтобы были простые примеры распечатаны.

Comment: У меня для таких вещей есть [репозиторий](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts) :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй ctrl+alt+L (reformat code), это должно сработать, если код больше длинны а4. В ином случае просто скопируй код в office word и распечатай оттуда.